# Solve as system of equations given by $b^n =(1-p)+p \frac{1}{2n+1} \frac{a^{2n+2}-1}{a^2-1}$

Tags: analysis, systems-of-equations

Let $b\ge 1$,  can we show that there exists an $0\le a $ and $p\in [0,1]$ such that

\begin{align}
b^{2n} =(1-p)+p \frac{1}{2n+1}  \frac{a^{2n+2}-1}{a^2-1},
\end{align}
for every posive integer $n$.

Note, that I am not interested in the solution only in the existence of the solution.

Note that for each $n$ this can easily be done. However, I want the statement to hold for all $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible for the equality to hold for $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ except for the trivial case $b=1$ where you can choose $p=0$.

If the equality were to hold for $b \gt 1$, then at the limit:

$$
\begin{align}
1 & = \lim_{n \to \infty} \cfrac{(1-p)+p \frac{1}{2n+1}  \frac{a^{2n+2}-1}{a^2-1}}{b^{2n}} \\
 & = \lim_{n \to \infty} \cfrac{1-p}{b^{2n}} - \lim_{n \to \infty} \cfrac{p}{(2n+1)(a^2-1)b^{2n}} + \lim_{n \to \infty} \cfrac{p\,a^{2n+2}}{(2n+1)(a^2-1)b^{2n}} \\
 & = 0 - 0 + \cfrac{p\,a^2}{a^2-1}\,\lim_{n \to \infty} \cfrac{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{2n}}{2n+1}
\end{align}
$$

The latter limit is $0$ if $a \le b$ and $\infty$ if $a \gt b$, so the resulting limit can not be $1$ regardless of $p,a$.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps you will be interested in this very similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2061628/solve-the-system-b2n-1-p-p-sum-k-0n-cn-k-q-a2k-for-ever-n