# Solve the system $ b^{2n} = (1-p) + p \sum_{k=0}^n c(n,k,q) a^{2k} $ for ever $n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, systems-of-equations, hypergeometric-function

Let $b\ge 1$ and $1 \le q \le 2$,  can we show that there exists an $0\le a \le  b$ and $p\in [0,1]$ such that

\begin{align}
 b^{2n} = (1-p) + p \sum_{k=0}^n   c(n,k,q)  a^{2k} 
\end{align}
for every integer $n\ge 1$ where the coefficients in the series have the following complicated expression
\begin{align}
c(n,k,q)=\frac{    \mathrm{B} \left( \frac{2k+1}{q}, \frac{2n-2k+1}{q}\right)  }{  (2n+1)  \mathrm{B}( \frac{2n+1}{q},\frac{1}{q} )   \mathrm{B} \left( 2k+1, 2n-2k+1\right) } 
\end{align}

where the beta function is defined as $\mathrm{B} \left( x, y\right)=\frac{\Gamma(x) \Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$.

**Solution for $q=1$.** If $q=1$ then it is not difficult to check that
\begin{align}
c(n,k,q)=1
\end{align}

and we have to solve

\begin{align}
 b^{2n} = (1-p) + p \sum_{k=0}^n     a^{2k} 
\end{align}
using the sum $\sum_{k=0}^n     a^{2k} =\frac{a^{2k+1}-1}{a^2-1}$ we have to solve

\begin{align}
 b^{2n} = (1-p) + p     \frac{a^{2k+1}-1}{a^2-1}
\end{align}
which is done by using $1-p=\frac{1}{b^2}$ and $a=b$.

**Solution for $q=1$.** For $q=2$ it is more tedious but one can check that the solution is given by $p=1$ and $a^2=b^2-1$.

So, the **question is** can we show this for $q \in (1,2)$.  Note that we are not interested in what the solution is but rather that the solution esits.

Comment: Is $n$ assumed to be strictly positive?

Comment: @dxiv Yes, $n\ge 1$.

Comment: `c(n,k,1)=1` But for example $c(1,0,1)=\frac{1}{3\,\operatorname{B}(3,4)}=20$. Is the formula for $c(n,k,q)$ the right one?

Comment: @dxiv yes, sorry about this. There was a typo. I have corrected the term. Now for $q=q$ we get  \begin{align}
c(n,k,q)=\frac{1    }{  (2n+1)  \mathrm{B}( 2n+1,1)    }  =1.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist no such $a,p$ in general. The following will derive $a,p$ from the equations for $n=1,2$, then substitute them for $n=3$ and show that the equality fails for $q=\frac{3}{2}$.

First note that $c(n,k,q)=c(n,n-k,q)$ and $c(n,0,q)=1$. Let $c=c(2,1,q)$ then:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{cases}
b^2 & = 1-\cancel{p}+p(\cancel{1}+a^2) & = 1 + pa^2 \\
b^4 & = 1 -\cancel{p} + p(\cancel{1}+a^4) + pc a^2 & = 1+pca^2+pa^4
\begin{align}
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

Eliminating $p$ between the equations gives $a^2$ then substituting back gives $p$. In the end:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
a^2 & = b^2 + 1 - c \\
p & = \frac{b^2-1}{b^2+1-c}
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

Let $d=c(3,1,q)=c(3,2,q)$ then the equation for $n=3$ is:

$$
b^6 = 1 - \cancel{p} + p(\cancel{1}+a^6) + pd(a^2+a^4) = 1+pa^2(a^4+da^2+d)
$$

Substituting $a,p$ as determined at the previous step, and after simple manipulations:

$$
(b^2+1-c)(b^4+b^2+1) = (b^2+1-c)\big((b^2+1-c)^2+d(b^2+1-c)+d\big)
$$

Since this must hold as a polynomial identity in $b$, the coefficients must match between the two sides. In particular, equating the free terms gives:

$$
1-c = (1-c)\big((1-c)^2+d(1-c) + d\big)
$$

So either $c=1$ or else:

$$
\begin{align}
(1-c)^2+d(1-c) + d = 1 \iff \cancel{1}-2c+c^2+d(2-c)=\cancel{1} \iff (c-2)(c-d)=0
\end{align}
$$

Therefore a necessary condition for the expansion to hold is for either of the following to be true:

$$
\begin{cases}
c(2,1,q)=1 & \quad\quad \text{(true for } q=1 \text{)}\\
c(2,1,q)=2 & \quad\quad \text{(true for } q=2 \text{)} \\
c(3,1,q)=c(2,1,q)
\end{cases}
$$

For $q=\frac{3}{2}$, however, none of the conditions hold true, therefore the expansion fails at $n=3$:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
c(2,1,\frac{3}{2}) & = \frac{6}{\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{10}{3}\right)} \simeq 1.59492 \\
c(3,1, \frac{3}{2}) & = \frac{27 \,\Gamma\left(\frac{16}{3}\right)}{26 \,\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{14}{3}\right)} \simeq 2.09188
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$